# each inside each loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with field elements with classes like required, class1, class2,class3 etc. Now I need to iterate through all the elements and display error message if any of the above classes are not satisfied. I have written the below jquery for required. Now I need to cascade other classes as well. Can anyone guide me on this?

```
<input class="required allowalphanum allownospace" type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" title="First name is required or the data entered was invalid" value=""/>
<input class="required allowalphanum allownospace" type="password" id="password" name="password" title="Password is required or the data entered was invalid" value=""/>
<input class="required confmpasswrd" type="password" id="cnfmPassword" name="cnfmPassword" title="Password needs to match the above field" value=""/>
```

jQuery fn

```
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
var input = $(this);
input.next('ul.errormessages').remove();
input.removeClass('highlight');
if (!input.val()) {
    input.addClass('highlight');
    var msg = $(this).attr('title');
    input.after('<ul class="errormessages"><li>'+msg+'</li></ul>');
    returnVal = false;
}
});
```

Now I need to first check if the required class is satisfied. Then I need to check for other classes as well if it allowsalphanumeric, allownospace, cnfmPassword etc..

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Why don't you use more descriptive names for the classes, e.g. `class="allow-alnum allow-nospace"`?

Comment: @Jack lol, It was entirely depended on his mind.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can check if elem has yourClass:

```
if ($('elem').hasClass('yourClass')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

With $.each, you can pass in the current index and element :

```
$('selector').each(function(i, e){
    if ($(e).hasClass('yourClass')) {   // e becomes each elem in the $('selector') object
        // do stuff with $(e)
    }
})
```

You could check for multiple classes:

```
$('selector').each(function(i, e){
    if ($(e).hasClass('yourClass') && $(e).hasClass('yourOtherClass') && $(e).hasClass('yourStuffOverHere')) {
        // do stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Robert..Thanks for your reply. Can I do this inside my each loop for the required? What I am looking for is, inside required loop, can i check for other classes as well?

Comment: Do you want to check if elem has both class names or either class names?

Comment: Whatever classes the elemnt has, it should check all.If for a given field, it has required, allowalphanum,allownospace etc, I need to check if that field satisfies all these and return a return value true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Solution similar to jQuery's validator plugin:

```
// List of validating functions for each class
var validators = {
    allowalphanum: function(val) {
        return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allownospace: function(val) {
        return !/\s/.test(val);
    }
};

$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.errormessages').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var msg = $(this).attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="errormessages"><li>'+msg+'</li></ul>');
        returnVal = false;
    }

    // Get all the classes of the current input
    if(this.className) {
        var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
        for(var p in classes) {
            if(classes[p] in validators) {
                returnVal = returnVal & validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**EDIT:** added a check whether className is defined

Comment: Hi, Can I do the above logic on blur of the fields having these classes? $('#submit_form > input').blur(function () {
 var input = $(this);
 if(input.hasClass('allowalphanum')){
  //regex
  return returnVal 
 }
}); I need to validate the fields when it blurs

Comment: Hi..It is giving className null or not an object when I run the above code in IE8. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to check whether the input has anny classes at all. Fixed it.
As for blur, you just can attach the function above to the blur event, that is, you'll have `$('#submit_form input').blur(function() {...` instead of `$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(...`